# C# string concatenation in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, string, lambda, string-concatenation

```
String qry = "p => p.Title == "Test" && P.Status=0;

myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyDetails(id).
  Where(Append qry string here).ToList();
```

I am trying to append my query string output to where in Lambda expression. It works fine if I take

```
myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyDetails(id).
  Where(p => p.Title == "Test" && P.Status=0).ToList();
```

But not like this

```
myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyDetails(id).
  Where("+ qry +").ToList();
```

How can I concatenate this and make lambda expression work.

My Controller code

```
   [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult MyProjects(int? id, string qry)
        {
            var dataAccessHelper = new DataAccessHelper(true);
            IList<ProjectEntity> myProjects;
            if (qry == null)
            {
                myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyProjects(id);
            }
            else
            {
                Expression<Func<ProjectEntity, bool>> expr = qry;
                myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyProjects(id).Where(expr).ToList();

            }

            var myProjectsViewModel = new MyProjectsViewModel() { GetMyProjects =                  myProjects };
            return View(myProjectsViewModel);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Function Expression. You will need the type for the `Where` clause, I am going to assume that your type is Project.

If you are using linq to sql you will need to construct an Expression

```
//assuming Project is type
Expression<Func<Project, bool>> expr = p => p.Title == "Test" && p.Status == 0;
```

If you are using linq to objects then you can omit the Expression

```
//assuming Project is type
Func<Project, bool> expr = p => p.Title == "Test" && p.Status == 0;
```

Now you can use this in your where clause

```
myProjects = dataAccessHelper.GetMyDetails(id).Where(expr).ToList();
```

*edit*

With regards to your edit. You can't really pass in a string to do this with. Your best bet would be to pass in the "Test" and the integer for status, and then put those into the expression.

```
public virtual ActionResult MyProjects(int? id, string title = "Title", int status = 0)
```

and then

```
Func<Project, bool> expr = p => p.Title == title && p.Status == status;
```

Comment: +1.btw. You can skip `Expression<>` in variable declaration if it's LINQ to Objects query.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - I added in the distinction just in case :)

Comment: this Expression seems to be completely new to me. My code shows cannot resolve symbol expression, details, expr. kindly let me know if I m missing any name space

Comment: @Usham - Yes, the `Expression` will require a namespace inclusion. `using System.Linq.Expressions;`

Comment: I updated my code with controller code where I am unable to get expression and TYPE mainly. Please suggest on code. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: It works fine if it is Func<Project, bool> expr = p => p.Title == "Test" && p.Status == 0; but it fails when I want to pass parameter qry as string. I am checking option to convert expr to string. Please check my controller cone and throw some idea.

Answer (score 1):

For converting strings to expressions, you will need to do some form of dynamic compilation. This blog post contains some options for doing this:

http://jp-labs.blogspot.com/2008/11/dynamic-lambda-expressions-using.html